# How to make Vector image in gradient?

Tags: java, android

[image]**There is a vector image file code. which is converting to Gradient Image.**
I want this vector image as gradient two circles.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="1024.000000dp"
    android:height="1024.000000dp"
    android:viewportWidth="1024.000000"
    android:viewportHeight="1024.000000">

    <group
            android:translateY="1024.000000"
            android:scaleX="0.100000"
            android:scaleY="-0.100000">
        <path
            android:fillColor="#000000"
            android:strokeWidth="1"
            android:pathData="M4750 10229 c-1481 -111 -2824 -843 -3722 -2029 -327 -433 -603 -959 -772 -1475 -238 -726 -312 
-1503 -216 -2260 128 -1003 543 -1931 1210 -2705 100 -117 372 -392 490 -495 431 -380 954 -700 1484 -910 433 -170 829 -271
 1311 -331 173 -22 813 -31 1010 -15 859 72 1667 349 2383 817 577 378 1079 875 1456 1444 154 232 221 349 341 591 274 555 440 
1143 500 1773 17 185 21 736 5 916 -84 969 -426
 1868 -1004 2640 -192 257 -509 597 -746 801 -856 736 -1890 1161 -3008 1238 -177 13 -554 12 -722 0z" />
    </group>
</vector>
```

Answer (score 1):

We can make vector gradient with merging both vector and shape. To merge both vector and shape we have to create layer-list as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:width="1024.000000dp"
            android:height="1024.000000dp"
            android:viewportWidth="1024.000000"
            android:viewportHeight="1024.000000">

            <group
                android:translateY="1024.000000"
                android:scaleX="0.100000"
                android:scaleY="-0.100000">
                <path
                    android:fillColor="#000000"
                    android:strokeWidth="1"
                    android:pathData="M4750 10229 c-1481 -111 -2824 -843 -3722 -2029 -327 -433 -603 -959 -772 -1475 -238 -726 -312
-1503 -216 -2260 128 -1003 543 -1931 1210 -2705 100 -117 372 -392 490 -495 431 -380 954 -700 1484 -910 433 -170 829 -271
 1311 -331 173 -22 813 -31 1010 -15 859 72 1667 349 2383 817 577 378 1079 875 1456 1444 154 232 221 349 341 591 274 555 440
1143 500 1773 17 185 21 736 5 916 -84 969 -426
 1868 -1004 2640 -192 257 -509 597 -746 801 -856 736 -1890 1161 -3008 1238 -177 13 -554 12 -722 0z" />
            </group>
        </vector>
    </item>

    <item>
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="#8df"/>
            <size
                android:width="48dp"
                android:height="48dp"
                />
            <gradient android:centerColor="@android:color/holo_purple"
                android:startColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
                android:endColor="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
                />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

**Hi, if you want above image without icon then here is the updated answer:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:width="1024dp"
        android:height="1024dp">
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="oval">
            <gradient
                android:startColor="@color/color1"
                android:centerColor="@color/color2"
                android:endColor="@color/color3"
                />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:width="900dp"
        android:height="900dp"
        android:gravity="center">
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="oval">
            <gradient
                android:startColor="@color/color4"
                android:centerColor="@color/color5"
                android:endColor="@color/color6"
                />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Comment: hi.. but I can't use layerlist..without using layer-list only edit in vector file it's possible?

Comment: can i know what the issue in using layerlist?

Comment: I have no issue to use layer list, But I want this type of image ..as above I have added in my question.(only background gradient Not icon consider)

Comment: i have updated my answer for background circles without plus icon as you want

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to generate form a default tool of Android studio [Vector Assets](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio#running)

I have generated Instagram icon form this tool.

```
<vector android:height="24dp" android:viewportHeight="1024"
    android:viewportWidth="1024" android:width="24dp"
    xmlns:aapt="http://schemas.android.com/aapt" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <path android:fillColor="#AFAFAF" android:pathData="M514.32,19.82c-271.89,0 -492.35,220.46 -492.35,492.46c0,271.9 220.46,492.35 492.35,492.35c271.91,0 492.36,-220.45 492.36,-492.35C1006.68,240.29 786.22,19.82 514.32,19.82z"/>
    <path android:pathData="M514.32,19.82c-271.89,0 -492.35,220.46 -492.35,492.46c0,271.9 220.46,492.35 492.35,492.35c271.91,0 492.36,-220.45 492.36,-492.35C1006.68,240.29 786.22,19.82 514.32,19.82z">
        <aapt:attr name="android:fillColor">
            <gradient android:endX="191.28621" android:endY="140.62901"
                android:startX="837.3545" android:startY="883.8457" android:type="linear">
                <item android:color="#FF5D3FD2" android:offset="0"/>
                <item android:color="#FFB829A9" android:offset="0.4244"/>
                <item android:color="#FFBE289D" android:offset="0.5009"/>
                <item android:color="#FFD0257E" android:offset="0.6383"/>
                <item android:color="#FFE62256" android:offset="0.7849"/>
                <item android:color="#FFE83156" android:offset="0.8147"/>
                <item android:color="#FFEE5755" android:offset="0.8718"/>
                <item android:color="#FFF89554" android:offset="0.9495"/>
                <item android:color="#FFFFC153" android:offset="1"/>
            </gradient>
        </aapt:attr>
    </path>
    <path android:fillColor="#00000000"
        android:pathData="M373.41,751.08L373.41,751.08l-0,-0L373.41,751.08zM655.24,252.01h0.01H655.24L655.24,252.01z"
        android:strokeColor="#FFFFFF" android:strokeWidth="1"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#FFFFFF" android:pathData="M514.32,688.04c96.96,0 175.84,-78.84 175.84,-175.76c0,-96.97 -78.88,-175.87 -175.84,-175.87c-96.95,0 -175.83,78.9 -175.83,175.87C338.49,609.2 417.37,688.04 514.32,688.04zM381.14,512.28c0,-73.49 59.74,-133.28 133.18,-133.28s133.19,59.79 133.19,133.28c0,73.44 -59.75,133.19 -133.19,133.19S381.14,585.72 381.14,512.28z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#FFFFFF" android:pathData="M689.68,804.29H338.96c-65.82,0 -119.37,-53.55 -119.37,-119.37V339.55c0,-65.82 53.55,-119.37 119.37,-119.37h350.72c65.82,0 119.37,53.55 119.37,119.37v345.37C809.05,750.74 755.5,804.29 689.68,804.29zM338.96,263.73c-41.8,0 -75.82,34.01 -75.82,75.82v345.37c0,41.8 34.01,75.82 75.82,75.82h350.72c41.8,0 75.82,-34.01 75.82,-75.82V339.55c0,-41.8 -34.01,-75.82 -75.82,-75.82H338.96z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#FFFFFF" android:pathData="M692.54,316.36c-15.38,0 -27.76,12.52 -27.76,27.79c0,15.37 12.38,27.72 27.76,27.72c15.26,0 27.78,-12.35 27.78,-27.72C720.32,328.88 707.8,316.36 692.54,316.36z"/>
</vector>
```